# How to append a hidden element and then submit using ajaxSubmit from the jQuery form plugin?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jquery-forms-plugin

I have the following event on a check box in CoffeeScript:

```
$('#check_box').click ->
  opts = 
    target: '#project_total'
    beforeSubmit: preSubmit
    success: postSubmit
  $('form').ajaxSubmit(opts)

preSubmit = ->
  $('input#running').remove()
  $('<input/>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('id', 'running').attr('name', 'running').attr('value', 'true').appendTo('form')
```

But the input element, #running, is not sent as part of the ajaxSubmit call.  All other form values are sent.  If I click the check box, then click the Submit button, the #running value is sent.

How can I send the value of #running along with the ajaxSubmit() call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send an hidden element with a form, you should use a Type="Hidden" in the input you want to send aswell. In this case your running should look something like

> `<input id="running" type="hidden" value="somevalue"/>`

and it should be sent along with the whole form.

This code is a bit confusing, why do you actually remove input#running and then create it afterward?

Comment: I had hidden set originally, but changed it to text for debugging.  I've changed it back now.  I remove input#running because this form could be submitted multiple times (if the user checks or unchecks the check box), and I only want one running element.

Comment: Ok sorry, I see what you wanna do now, JQuery can be tricky sometimes about items you remove and place depending on when and how, that's probably the problem. I would've to try a bit to give you another answer, sadly I'm not really familiar with CoffeeScript.

Comment: I'd always include "running" and then just append values 1/0 to it instead of removing and adding back the entire option.